# Can mobs spawn in water?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a mob trap but I don't know if mobs spawn in water.  Does anyone know?

Comment: One question per post, please. Asking how to build a mob trap should be asked separately, so I've edited it out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Mobs do not spawn on any transparent block. These include:

- Water
- Glass
- Half slabs
- leaves
- ice
- Glowstone

Comment: except for Squid, Squids need water to spawn in.

Comment: true. Water mobs ignore that rule.

Comment: Also note, if you're dealing with a spawner, mobs will spawn in the air around a spawner.